# adding class to show active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show active slide for a slide show. I have hard coded the divs since I know how many slides would be there so it looks like this

```
var activeSlide = $('<div class="slidePosHolder"><div class="slidePos"></div><div class="slidePos"></div><div class="slidePos"></div></div>');
```

Now I am adding an active class which I am trying to index it to this `.views-field-field-slide-description`..The concept is when the class changes it shows the active state on the current slide. Rest of my JQuery looks like this

```
$('.slidePos').removeClass('active');
        $('.slidePos').eq($(this).index('.views-field-field-slide-description')).addClass('active');
```

It is adding the class to the starting slide but not removing it as the slides progress. I am assuming I am indexing it wrong. Any ideas? I am using jquery 1.4.4

Comment: `toggleClass` may help in this situation.

Comment: Any reason why you are still using jQuery 1.4.4?

Comment: good question. The problem is drupal 7 gives it by default. I could try changing it but it might break things